# Print a ballot!

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

As you all know, today is election day!

Your task today is to print out a ballot, given an input.

If the input is `Hillary Clinton`, print:

```
Hillary Clinton   ===-----===>
Donald Trump      ===     ===>
____________      ===     ===>
```

However, if the input is `Donald Trump`, print:

```
Hillary Clinton   ===     ===>
Donald Trump      ===-----===>
____________      ===     ===>
```

If it is something else, write it on the third line:

```
Hillary Clinton   ===     ===>
Donald Trump      ===     ===>
Oliver Ni         ===-----===>
```

<sup><sub>(Technically, I'm not 18 yet...)</sub></sup>

Remember, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the fewest bytes wins.

Comment: No "none of the above option"? :)

Comment: @KritixiLithos Hm, nah...

Comment: Any max length on the name of "something else"? (There are 18 characters before the first equal sign in your examples)

Comment: Is it case sensitive or insensitive? Judging by the test cases I'm assuming sensitive at the moment.

Comment: @KritixiLithos but that would be rigging the system!

Answer (score 6):

## Jelly, <s>55</s> 53 bytes

```
³ẇị⁾- x5⁾ =,”=x3¤j;”>ṭ
ṭ“Gụ©l⁴“%eŻƤ(»”_x12¤ṭQḣ3z⁶ZÇ€Y
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=wrPhuofhu4vigb4tIHg14oG-ID0s4oCdPXgzwqRqO-KAnT7hua0K4bmt4oCcR-G7pcKpbOKBtOKAnCVlxbvGpCjCu-KAnV94MTLCpOG5rVHhuKMzeuKBtlrDh-KCrFk&input=&args=IkpvaG4gTWNBZmVlIg)

#### Explanation

```
³ẇị⁾- x5⁾ =,”=x3¤j;”>ṭ   Helper link. Argument: row
³ẇ                       Check if the user's vote is in this row
  ị⁾-                    Take "-" if it was, " " otherwise
      x5                 Take five of that character
        ⁾ =,”=           Take the array [" =", "="]
              x3         Turn it into ["   ===", "==="]
                ¤        Combine the two previous steps into a nilad
                 j       Join the list by the five character string
                  ;”>    Add ">"
                     ṭ   Prepend the original row

ṭ“Gụ©l⁴“%eŻƤ(»”_x12¤ṭQḣ3z⁶ZÇ€Y   Main link. Argument: vote
 “Gụ©l⁴“%eŻƤ(»                   Take the array ["Hillary Clinton", "Donald Trump"]
ṭ                                Add the user's vote to the list
              ”_                 Take "_"
                x12              Take twelve times that
                   ¤             Combine the two previous steps into a nilad
                    ṭ            Add that string to the list
                     Q           Remove duplicates
                      ḣ3         Take the three first items
                        z⁶       Transpose, padding with spaces
                          Z      Transpose back
                           Ç€    Apply the helper to each row
                             Y   Join with newlines
```

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>74</s> <s>59</s> 57 bytes

Uses [CP-1252](http://www.cp1252.com) encoding.

```
”ŽÏaryµÍ””¹Ñ Trump”I'_12×)Ù3£vyð18yg-×„ -¹yQè5×'=3×.ø'>J,
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCdxb3Dj2FyecK1w43igJ3igJ3CucORIFRydW1w4oCdSSdfMTLDlynDmTPCo3Z5w7AxOHlnLcOX4oCeIC3CuXlRw6g1w5cnPTPDly7DuCc-Siw&input=QmVybmllIFNhbmRlcnM)

Answer (score 4):

### Python 2, 127 bytes

```python
X=['Hillary Clinton','Donald Trump']
i=input()
X+=[[i],['_'*12]][i in X]
for x in X:print x.ljust(18)+'==='+' -'[i==x]*5+'===>'
```

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 149 bytes

```js
s=>['Hillary Clinton','Donald Trump',0].map(S=>((S?S:s||'____________')+p+p+p+p+p).slice(0,18)+`===${!S^S==s?(s=0,'-----'):p}===>`,p='     ').join`
`
```

#### Demo

```js
let f =

s=>['Hillary Clinton','Donald Trump',0].map(S=>((S?S:s||'____________')+p+p+p+p+p).slice(0,18)+`===${!S^S==s?(s=0,'-----'):p}===>`,p='     ').join`
`

console.log(f('Hillary Clinton'))
console.log(f('Donald Trump'))
console.log(f('Obi-Wan Kenobi'))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 7, <s>390</s> <s>339</s> 335 bytes

```
String c(String s){String h="Hillary Clinton",d="Donald Trump",r=h+"   ===Q===>\n"+d+"      ===X===>\nZ===J===>";boolean H=h.equals(s),D=d.equals(s);for(int i=s.length();i++<18;s+=" ");return r.replace(H?"Q":D?"X":"J","-----").replace(H|D?"Z":"~","____________      ").replaceAll(H?"X|J":D?"Q|J":"Q|X","     ").replace(H|D?"~":"Z",s);}
```

**Ungolfed & test code:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/KdHHEl)

```
class M{
  static String c(String s){
    String h = "Hillary Clinton",
           d = "Donald Trump",
           r = h+"   ===Q===>\n"+d+"      ===X===>\nZ===J===>";
    boolean H = h.equals(s),
            D = d.equals(s);
    for(int i = s.length(); i++ < 18; s += " ");
    return r.replace(H?"Q":D?"X":"J", "-----")
            .replace(H|D?"Z":"~", "____________      ")
            .replaceAll(H?"X|J":D?"Q|J":"Q|X", "     ")
            .replace(H|D?"~":"Z", s);
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(c("Hillary Clinton"));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(c("Donald Trump"));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(c("Anyone else?.."));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(c("S"));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(c("Anyone who is willing to take the job"));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hillary Clinton   ===-----===>
Donald Trump      ===     ===>
____________      ===     ===>

Hillary Clinton   ===     ===>
Donald Trump      ===-----===>
____________      ===     ===>

Hillary Clinton   ===     ===>
Donald Trump      ===     ===>
Anyone else?..    ===-----===>

Hillary Clinton   ===     ===>
Donald Trump      ===     ===>
S                 ===-----===>

Hillary Clinton   ===     ===>
Donald Trump      ===     ===>
Anyone who is willing to take the job===-----===>
```

Answer (score 1):

## [V](http://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 104 bytes

```
OHillary Clinton³ ³=µ ³=>YpRDonald Trump   p15r_ñ/^¨á« á«¾©.*î¨.*î©*\1
22|5r-Gdññ3GjéRDk@"Í_/ 
22|5r-
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=T0hpbGxhcnkgQ2xpbnRvbsKzIMKzPcK1IMKzPT4bWXBSRG9uYWxkIFRydW1wICAgG3AxNXJfw7EvXsKow6HCqyDDocKrwr7CqS4qw67CqC4qw67CqSpcMQoyMnw1ci1HZMOxw7EzR2rDqVJEa0AiG8ONXy8gCjIyfDVyLQ&input=SGlsbGFyeSBDbGludG9u)

This answer is way too hacky, and way too long. I guess that's what you get when you design a golfing-language off of a text-editor. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: wait what does `O` do? It looks like it functions like `i`

Comment: @conor That's correct, they both enter insert mode. The only difference is *where* in the buffer the cursor starts. There's also `iIaAoOsSR` that all enter insert mode in some way or another

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 210 bytes

```
@set s=%1
@call:l %1 "Hillary Clinton"
@call:l %1 "Donald Trump"
@call:l %1 %s%
@exit/b
:l
@set v=     
@if %1==%2 set v=-----&set s=____________
@set t=%~2                  
@echo %t:~0,18%===%v%===^>
```

Note: the line `@set v=` has 5 trailing spaces, and the line `@set t=%~2` has 18. Accepts input as a quoted command-line parameter.

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 266 Bytes

Golfed:

```
string B(string s){var h="Hilary Clinton".PadRight(17);var d="Donald Trump".PadRight(17);var r="===     ===>\n";var c=r.Replace(" ", "-");var b="____________".PadRight(17);return s==h.Trim()?s.PadRight(17)+c+d+r+b+r:s==d.Trim()?h+r+d+c+b+r:h+r+d+r+s.PadRight(17)+c;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
public string B(string s)
{
  var h = "Hilary Clinton".PadRight(17);
  var d = "Donald Trump".PadRight(17);
  var r = "===     ===>\n";
  var c = r.Replace(" ", "-");
  var b = "____________".PadRight(17);
  return s == h.Trim() ? s.PadRight(17) + c + d + r + b + r :
    s == d.Trim() ? h + r + d + c + b + r :
      h + r + d + r + s.PadRight(17) + c;
}
```

*Tried to create a Func for all those PadRights...Exactly the same byte count...*

Testing:

```
var printABallot = new PrintABallot();
Console.WriteLine(printABallot.B("Hilary Clinton"));

Hilary Clinton   ===-----===>
Donald Trump     ===     ===>
____________     ===     ===>


Console.WriteLine(printABallot.B("Donald Trump"));

Hilary Clinton   ===     ===>
Donald Trump     ===-----===>
____________     ===     ===>


Console.WriteLine(printABallot.B("Kanye West"));

Hilary Clinton   ===     ===>
Donald Trump     ===     ===>
Kanye West       ===-----===>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3.6, 132 bytes

```
i=input()
s=['Hillary Clinton','Donald Trump','_'*12]
if x not in s:s[2]=i
for k in s:print(f'{k:18}==={" -"[k==i]*5}===>')
```

Uses [3.6's new f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 76 bytes

```
V{+_tW!}zJ[*\_12"Donald Trump""Hillary Clinton")Jzs[.[Nd18K*\=3*?qzN\-d5K\>
```